# UWP C++: Writing only instead of reading to a global variable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, uwp, global-variables

I have a separate header file for where I declare global variables. I have included that header file in pch.h which is included in every .cpp file. `#include "variable.h"` I now need to call the variable and read it in an if statment to start some code. Before compilation, no errors are shown in Visual Studio. However, when I compile the code, it returns error:

```
Error   LNK2005 "bool ahschecked" (?ahschecked@@3_NA) already defined in checkin.xaml.obj   pch.h
```

The variable is  "ahschecked" which is type Boolean and the file I am trying to read the global variable from is checkin.xaml.obj, the original declaration of the variable is in pch.h

This worked before in windows forms but when I transferred over to UWP, I was unable to get it to work.

---

I have recreated this issue with a smaller program.

Var.h (where the global variable is stored)

```
#pragma once
extern bool globalbool = false;
#pragma endregion
```

pch.h (automatically included in every .cpp)

```
#pragma once
#include <collection.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include "App.xaml.h"
#include "var.h"
```

MainPage.xaml.cpp (attempting to read from global var)

```
#incldue "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"

void testapp::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e) {
if (::globalbool == false)
{
// do something
}
}
```

Comment: Did you declare the `bool globalbool` outside the `var.h`?

Comment: No, where would I declare it if I tried doing that?

Comment: Declare it in MainPage.xaml.cpp just before `void::testapp::MainPag....` like :`bool globalbool=false;`. The variable used with `extern` has to be declared atleast once outside the header

Comment: @Rhnbmpl It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by declaring the global variable in the header file without any values attached to it then attaching the values to it later outside in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you didn't declare the global variable as `extern` but without seeing any code it's hard to be sure.

You should *declare* your global variables as `extern` in a header file, and then in one source file you should also *define* the global variable without `extern`.

This way of declaring **and** defining global variables is correct for any C++ program. It makes no difference whether you are writing a windows forms program or a UWP program.

Since you have a header file for global variable declarations, it would also make sense to have a source file for global variable definitions as well.

Comment: My code does have the extern keyword ahead of all the declared variables.

Comment: @RichardWei It's impossible to know what is wrong without seeing your code. Put together a small program with one global variable that has this problem, and post the code here.If you do that it'll get sorted out very quickly.

Comment: I have included a test program that recreates the exact error. Please advise what I should do. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardWei So that code is complete and produces an `"globalbool" already defined in ...` error message? I'm just asking because to me it looks like that code should produce a different error message.

Comment: @RichardWei Well then I give up, there's something important you're not telling me but I have no idea what it is. All I can suggest is that you reduce your code even further (for instance do you need all those header files in pch.h?). You have approach this systematically, eventually by reducing your code to the absolute minimum you'll get rid of the error. When you do that last thing you removed from your code was the cause of the error. All you need to know to use global variables in C++ is in my answer above (or in any decent C++ book).

Comment: One other possibility is that you are executing the build process wrongly. So the code you think you are compiling is not the code you are actually compiling. Since you've moved to a new platform (UWP instead of windows forms) that is a distinct possibility. In fact at present I'd say it's the most likely explanation.