# Proper way of passing parameters between UWP pages?

Tags: c++, parameters, uwp

I currently need to pass about 10-15 boolean variables and 1 string variable between 3 and 5 pages in a C++ UWP program. I've tried using global variables in a header file but due to the structure of UWP, it ends up being duplicated in each page. I stumbled across this post on SO: [Pass some parameters between pages in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304615/pass-some-parameters-between-pages-in-uwp)

It seems like a viable option but I want to know how to do exactly what is listed in that post but in C++ and with boolean variables. I don't have any idea of how to translate C# code into C++ code but it looks awfully similar. Another big question I have from that post is where do I declare the public class? In the header file? In the `.cpp` file?

Comment: Your header file should contain merely declarations, not definitions, of the globals. If you want to do it the way mentioned in the linked article, then create a WinRT class that contains your desired information and pass a reference to that. (The details depend on which flavor of C++ you are using. C++/CX? C++/WinRT? C++/ABI?)

Comment: @RaymondChen I am currently using c++/CX.

Comment: In that case, you can define a new `ref class RestaurantParams` in a header file and `ref new` it. Pass it as the navigation parameter, and in `OnNavigatedTo` do `auto parameters = safe_cast<RestaurantParameters^>(e->Parameter);`

Comment: @RaymondChen, is it possible for you to create this in a small test program? I’m still fairly new to UWP development band I don’t understand where you would put half the things you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: An example of a custom `ref class` is the [CaptureFailedEventArgs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/SimpleCommunication/cpp/Utils.h#L22) in one of the UWP samples. (One of many examples.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks. I'm still a bit confused, however, So I declare a ref class in the header file, then where do I ref new it? In the .cpp file? In the link, it uses "var parameters = new RestaurantParams();" how would you type this out in c++?

Comment: The C# `var parameters = new RestaurantParams();` translates to C++/CX as `auto parameters = ref new RestaurantParams();`. The C# `var parameters = (RestaurantParams)e.Parameter;` translates to C++/CX as `auto parameters = safe_cast<RestaurantParams^>(e->Parameter);` - The logic is the same. Just some syntactic differences between the two languages.

Comment: Ok, so I created my ref class but I named it "variables". When I declare a boolean variable like this: 

ref class variables
 {
 public:
  bool test;
 };

I get an error from the compiler that says:

Error C3984 'checkuwp::variables': a non-value type cannot have any public data members 'test'

Comment: `ref class` cannot have public data members. Only properties, methods, and events. Make it a read-only property. See the example I linked to earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extern` keyword when declaring variables in the header like: `extern int global_var`(<--In header). Then, when you are using this variable for the first time, declare it only once in your cpp file like: `int global_var`(<--First time use in cpp). Then you can reuse this variable by including the header and simply using the variable in your operations `global_var=x`(<--Any other file where the above header is included) or whatever. It will reflect the change across the program wherever the header is included.

Comment: Like I said, I have tried this before. I even made a post about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956075/uwp-c-writing-only-instead-of-reading-to-a-global-variable?rq=1